# Next Auth "useSession" syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, next.js, next-auth

I'm reading through the [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client) documentation, and I'm confused by the syntax for the `useSession` hook. Here's how it's used in the documentation

```js
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
```

However, I don't understand why we're assigning `session` to `data`. Wouldn't we achieve the same result if we just did this:

```js
const { data, status } = useSession()
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a naming convention in the next-auth world to use the term 'session' when using useSession(), so it'd be similar to when using getSession(), where in both cases session object includes a user object and expires string.
So long story short you can assign it to whatever var name you want, or just directly use the data variable.

Comment: Ah I see, we're just [renaming](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming) the variable while destructuring. I didn't even know you could do this, thanks!